# Configure IDEA to place generated code near cursor

Tags: intellij-idea

Inside a method of some class, I typed a field name that doesn't exist yet. I invoked the *Generate > Field* command. IDEA generated the field but placed it somewhere far up the class - probably at a position determined by *Code Style > Arrangement*.

Is there a way to configure IDEA to place newly generated code as close to the cursor as possible? E.g., in the example above I wanted the new field to be placed right above my method.